# How Ethereum 2.0 and sharding will apply to private Ethereum with PoA consensus (Clique)?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, eth-2.0, clique, geth-clique

We're about to run the private Ethereum PoA chain based on [Clique](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network) and thinking how would we support it for ages. Hence we're wondering:

1. Whether Ethereum 2.0 updates (London, etc) are even applicable to PoA chain? Ethereum 2.0 is a migration to PoS consensus algorithm, which seems odd as we already have PoA in the chain.
2. Will this chain receive updates to be conformant with the Ethereum mainnet chain?
3. When sharding is introduced in the Ethereum mainnet chain, how PoA/Clique chain will pick it up? Is it possible to answer this question now or the solution is yet to be developed?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whether Ethereum 2.0 updates (London, etc) are even applicable to PoA chain? Ethereum 2.0 is a migration to PoS consensus algorithm, which seems odd as we already have PoA in the chain.

They are not.

> Will this chain receive updates to be conformant with the Ethereum mainnet chain?

It depends on you, it is your chain. No one else can tell.

> When sharding is introduced in the Ethereum mainnet chain, how PoA/Clique chain will pick it up? Is it possible to answer this question now or the solution is yet to be developed?

It does not pick them up. Also, Ethereum sharding roadmap is not yet complete, so it is impossible to tell what Ethereum sharding solution will be.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately it is what it is.